# ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from partially initialized module 'profiles.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am importing Profile from profiles.models into meta.models, but showing the subject error. Can't find cutom solution, even though there are similar problems with different solutions out there but not working in my case.

**Here is my profiles.models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from meta.models import Designation

class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text = 'Foreign Key From User')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='no_picture.png')
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**Here is my meta.models, where i am importing from profiles.models**

```
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import Profile
class Designation(models.Model):
    DesignationName  = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=True,null= True)
    DesignationScale = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.DesignationName)

class DutyPlaceSensitivity(models.Model):
    sensitivity = models.CharField(max_length = 12, blank=True, null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sensitivity)

class DutyPlaces(models.Model):
    DutyPlaceName = models.CharField(max_length =20, blank = True, null = True)
    sensitivity = models.ForeignKey(DutyPlaceSensitivity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ActingAs(models.Model):
    acting_as_title = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.acting_as_title)

class PlaceOfPosting(models.Model):
    UserProfile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    acting_as  = models.ForeignKey(ActingAs, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.UserProfile} - {self.acting_as}"

class TaskType(models.Model):
    taskTypeName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    taskDescription = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.taskTypeName)
class TaskPriority(models.Model):
    priority_title = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.priority_title)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    task_description = models.TextField()
    task_type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assign_by = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    assign_to = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    task_priority = models.ForeignKey(TaskPriority, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    #time_stamp  = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_add = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.task_name} --{self.assign_by}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the issues:

1/ To avoid cicular imports, you can use strings to declare foreign key target model, syntax: "app.Model".

```
class PlaceOfPosting(models.Model):
      UserProfile = models.OneToOneField("profiles.Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

2/ On_delete is not available on ManyToManyField since Django will handle the intermediate table for you.

3/ When a model has multiple FK or M2M on the same second model, related_name must be defined (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work ? It didn't solve your circular import or it did not find "profiles.Profile" ?

Comment: Same Error!

ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile' from partially initialized module 'profiles.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: And you changed all your foreign keys in meta.models so that the import of Profile has been removed without issue ? 
I gave you an example but in your case it will be faster to remove the Designation import in profiles.models and change the designation foreign key in Profile to the string notation "meta.Designation"

Comment: Now that error is gone but showing the following errors!
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Comment: Here it is:
env-tm/src/meta/models.py", line 50, in Tasks
    assign_by = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  File "/media/thenerds/TheNerdBox/env-tm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1387, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/media/thenerds/TheNerdBox/env-tm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 108, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Comment: There is no need for on_delete parameter for ManyToManyField

Comment: Thank You So Much It worked Well! But there is another thing poped Up.
meta.Tasks.assign_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Profile.tasks_set' for 'meta.Tasks.assign_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'meta.Tasks.assign_to'.

Comment: HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'meta.Tasks.assign_by' or 'meta.Tasks.assign_to'.
meta.Tasks.assign_to: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Profile.tasks_set' for 'meta.Tasks.assign_to' clashes with reverse accessor for 'meta.Tasks.assign_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'meta.Tasks.assign_to' or 'meta.Tasks.assign_by'.

Comment: Define a related name for your M2M in Tasks
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Thank You So Much! It worked Perfectly, You made my life easire and add motivation to go further. Salute!